# The Guillou-Quisquater Identification Scheme

Tags: rsa, modulo, algebra, pki

Can you please elucidate how it is computed? I am desperate .... i don't know what i am missing here.

**Example:**

Suppose the TA chooses p = 467 and q = 479, so n = 223693. Suppose also that b = 503 and Alice’s secret integer u = 101576. Then she will compute

[Original_formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfIcl.jpg)

How can I compute (u^(-1))^b to be larger than **n** (or at least larger than 0)? What am I missing?

Original source: http://flylib.com/books/en/3.230.1.96/1/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Comment: u^(-1) probably means u^(-1) (mod n), so it is a modular inverse (Extended euclidean algorithm). Then, (u^(-1))^b (mod n) is a modular exponentiation.